# Azure search filtering performance over Edm.Int32 and Collection(Edm.String)

Tags: azure, faceted-search, azure-cognitive-search

I'm using Azure Search on my e-commerce site, and now want to implement filtering.

I've faced issue with performance. I have index with products. Each product belong to category. Each category can have nested subcategories. 
My business purpose is when customer is on category page i need to show products even from subcategories, so i have doubts about how to store this relation(products to categories) in azure products index.
I'm considering two possibilities:

1. I can store only products category id in field with type Edm.Int32. Then when customer goes to this category i query to my sql server to get all subcategory ids and then construct my query to index like this

> categoryId eq 34 or categoryId eq 36 or categoryId eq 37 ...

2. Other way is to create field with type Collection(Edm.String) and to store products category id and nested categories ids in this field and then my query to index would look like this

> categoryIds/any(c: c eq '35')

So which way will be faster?

Comment: You mention querying SQL Server in option #1. Would you have to do so for option #2 as well?

Comment: Yes, but that's not the point. I wrote that just for example. I can store categories ids in local cache, so it wont be performance problem to fetch category id or category id with subcategories ids.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to clarify this point before trying to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option #2 is likely faster since the number of documents in the index will be far fewer, but the only way to be sure is to run some experiments with your data and queries. Overall query performance is going to depend on other factors like whether you're doing full-text search, faceting, geo-spatial, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I've made some tests, and conclusion is that both options takes approximately same time, it was about 300ms. I didn't notice considerable difference.

Comment: That makes sense. Likely filter execution for your queries is best-case and is linear with the number of unique terms being indexed rather than the number of documents.